# Change the color of a bar button in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, rightbarbuttonitem

I have the following code in my viewDidLoad of my containing view:

```
// Now add the next button
UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(self)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nextButton;
```

The UINavigationController parent has this in viewDidLoad:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

How do I just customize the rightBar button to change the background color and maybe the text color?

Comment: What does the above code do instead?

Comment: It keeps the bar black and the bar button black and the text color white.

Answer (score 19):

You have to set the tintColor property on the button after you assign the button.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nextButton;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

instead of

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nextButton;
```

Comment: I am experiencing exactly this issue, trying to set my bar button items to [UIColor YellowColor] , but the assignment order and the code above does not work.

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to have the **same color for all bar buttons** you can use the following line of code:

```
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

in your app delegate.

Comment: but that won't work if you just want the right one to change, correct? I probably have to create a button with an image and then cast that to a uibarbutton then

Comment: I am simply using self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; and it changes the button colour. can you explain further what are you doing ?

Answer (score 4):

Try below code you can set color of button as well text color

```
UIView *customBarButtonView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];

UIButton *buttonDone = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[buttonDone addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

buttonDone.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   // or try this one
// buttonDone.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

buttonDone.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 50, 30);

buttonDone.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:141.0/255.0 green:209.0/255.0 blue:205.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
buttonDone.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Light" size:20.0f];
[buttonDone setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customBarButtonView addSubview:buttonDone];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:customBarButtonView];
```

Answer (score 1):

working code.. try this.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(back:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;
```