# iOS change custom bar button text color when the button becomes available

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

So I have a registration page (and multiple other places through the registration process where this will be implemented) that has a Next button, which is set up as a custom UIButton dragged onto the nav bar.  As users enter in their registration information, I want to change the color of the text from grey when it is unavailable, to a custom green color. I've read some other threads, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088428/change-the-color-of-a-bar-button-in-ios-7) , but they haven't been any help.  I think I'm doing what they told me to correctly, but I'm getting different results than I want.  Right now my code looks like this:

```
-(void)checkCompletion
{
    if( emailEntered && passwordEntered && [_password.text length] >= 5)
    {
        [_nextBarButtonItem setEnabled:YES];
        [_nextButton setEnabled:YES];
        [_nextButton.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor customGreen]];
        [_nextButton setTintColor:[UIColor customGreen]];
        [_nextBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor customGreen]];
        nextAvailable = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        nextAvailable = NO;
    }
}
```

_nextBarButtonItem is the barButtonItem, and _nextButton is the UIButton I dragged onto the navigation bar, which is underneath _nextBarBUttonItem in the hierarchy.  customGreen is a category with its header file `#include`'d into my prefix.pch, as I use the color throughout the app.  This function gets called when textfields return and when the password is edited, so I can make the button available before the return key is pressed if users don't want to dismiss the keyboard first.

I have tried several methods, such as making the button my customGreen on the storyboard and disabling both the barButtonItem and the button itself underneath the barButtonItem in the hierarchy, hoping it would grey it out, but the button is still green, you just can't press it.  I made the button grey on the storyboard, then call this function, but the text ends up changing to white instead of the green color.  I tried explicitly defining the color as I set it, but I get the same result.  I do not want my back button to turn this green color, only the next button when it becomes available to press.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works for me (although, the only line you need is the one that sets the titleLabel's textColor). Are you sure the code enters the if statement, and that _nextButton is not nil?

Comment: @rdelmar 100% sure.  I don't see how else the button could become enabled and change from grey to white.  I may have some weird tint on it or something?  Thanks for letting me know the code is good, though.  I must just have some weird setting somewhere that needs changing.  For now, rather than change the color of the text, I hid the UIButton and kept its color as green.  That way, you can't even see the button until you've entered in all the required information to press it and it's the color I want it to be.  I've moved on to other challenges, but I'll be sure to revisit this later.